# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16

Tags: python

I have a problem with conversion from string to an integer.
I have function which return variable `` a = 00007fff`90492630 ``. This variable has type Unicode. This is the address of the function that I will use to install breakpoints via pykd (plugin for windbg).
At the next function, I would like to convert this variable to `int`, using `int(a,16)`.
But i have this error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '00007fff`90492630'

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Post portion of code where you have the problem so we can reproduce it... This doesnt tell me anything.

Comment: A backtick ` isn't a hexadecimal digit. Should this be two numbers, or do you need to remove the backtick?

Comment: I doubt the "`" can be converted to int.

Comment: Thank you for you answers! If i delete " ` " from my address, it will not make it invalid?

Comment: Show us what is generating this address.

Comment: I use pykd for windbg. a= pykd.dbgCommand("x " + func_name) return a.split()[0] .

Comment: a= pykd.dbgCommand("x " + func_name) , the result is = 00007fff`90492630 ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap

Comment: and after i use a.split()[0] and result is '00007fff`90492630'

Comment: "ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap" is func_name

Comment: after a.split()[0] i need to convert this value to int for installation of breakpoint.

Comment: change
pykd.dbgCommand("x " + func_name)
to
getOffset(func_name) 
the last returns address

Answer (score 1):

If you need to remove the tick in the code, you can do :

```
a = '00007fff`90492630'
b = int(a.translate(str.maketrans({'`':""})), 16)
print(b)
```

Comment: Thank you. I will test it. I hope that address will be valid.

Answer (score 0):

You got a single quote\tick inside your string.

When deleting it, you got the following output :

```
>>> int("00007fff90492630", 16)
140735614101040
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use pykd.expr it converts any windbg constant / symbols / expression to 64 bit long value

If you want to get offset of a function, use pykd.getOffset(func_name) instead of dbgCommand('x ' + func_name )